Polynomials as a Linear Combination
I have read that the set of all Polynomials Pⁿ are also a set of vector spaces.
And the explain I read, said that apart from following all the properties of a vector space (identity, communtativity, etc.), it is also the linear combination of scalars (coefficients) and vectors (variables).
But, as far as I know Polynomials can be of any degree and not necessarily be linear. So, are Polynomials really a linear combination of scalars and vectors and if so, how?

I think your confusion is due to the fact that the word "linear" is used in more than one way -- linear polynomials as being 1st degree polynomials (or at most 1st degree polynomials; author usage/definitions vary on this particular issue) and polynomials being linear combinations of powers of $x$ (i.e. the polynomial $3x^4 - 5x^3 + x^2 - 2x + 3$ is a linear combination of "vectors" in the set ${1,,x,,x^2,,x^3,,x^4}).$

@Dave L. Renfro, Thank for the point, I really didn't know the other usage of linear. P.S.- I was truly thinking linear in terms of degree.

FYI, there are several (English) words much worse than "linear" for having multiple mathematical meanings. My guess for the worst offender is "normal" -- see Universal meaning of 'normal' (note also normal number and normal topological space usages). Another offender much worse than "linear" are various versions of "modular" -- What is the origin of the term "modular" in different areas?
